# SQLAlchemy: Efficient way of merging duplicate tags

Tags: python, database, algorithm, database-design, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have a database full of `Tag` objects. Each `Tag` has an `id` and a `name`. In the beginning of making the database I allowed for case sensitive `Tags`, however, I later realized I didn't need/want this capability, so I started forcing each `name` to be lowercase before storing the `Tag`.

Now I have all these remnants of different `names` which would now be stored under the same `Tag` but previously weren't. For example,

```
Trendy, trendy
NotHalfBad, Nothalfbad, nothalfbad
SQL, sql, Sql
```

I am using Python and SQLAlchemy. I have created a function to clean up this mess that looks something like this:

```
todelete = []

for t1 in Session.query(Tag):
    if t1 not in todelete: # If we haven't already encountered this tag
        for t2 in Session.query(Tag).filter_by(name_insensitive=t1.name):
            if t1.id != t2.id:
                merge(t1,t2) # Calls a function I made that merges the two tags
                todelete.append(tag)
                Session.commit()

# Mark everything for deletion
for tag in todelete:
    Session.delete(tag)

# Now commit the deletes
Session.commit()
```

This is horribly inefficient. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a tool for one-time use, do you really have to care about efficiency? Just let it run for a minute (or several), rather than spending even more time optimizing it.

That being said, queries are more expensive than Python loops, so loading all the Tags into a list first, and then looping over that list both times, should speed things up:

```
for t1 in tags:
    if t1 not in todelete:
        for t2 in tags:
            if t2.name_insensitive == t1.name:
                merge(t1,t2)
                todelete.append(tag)
```

Also, remove the `commit` call in the loop. Not only is it expensive, but if some other process changes the DB, the list of tags you're looping over could get out of sync.

Of course, the a proper way to make things more efficient is profiling first, and then concentrating on specific problems. You should do that if you're serious about performance.

Comment: My database is pretty large. At the rate it was going it'd take several hours. Perhaps I am doing something terribly wrong? Either way, I will take your advice. That should cut down on time.

Comment: Well, my SQLAlchemy experience shows that cutting database queries down to a minimum is the best way to speed things up. And you sure were doing a lot of queries. You might want to turn turn [echo](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine) on and watch for any SQL you can eliminate – e.g. if merge() also does some queries, [joinedload](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/loading.html) the needed data in the „all tags“ query.